# Can I find the maximum magnetic flux of my magnet knowing the magnetic flux density? (and also for multiple stacked together)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, home-experiment

I'm working on an extended essay in physics for IB with my experiment relating to the magnet down a copper tube experiment. I'm trying to find the terminal velocity with my independent variable being adding more magnets each time (e.g. first time one magnet, then 2, then 3 ect.).

My problem is I need to compare my experiment values to the theoretical ones. I've taken an equation from a paper (Íñiguez et. al.) but it requires the "maximum flux" of the magnet. I know the flux density of my magnet (1294 gauss) and multiplying by the surface area seems to work well to find the flux. *However, I don't know how to find this for multiple magnets together as (i assume) the flux density changes.*

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.